# CI/CD Pipeline Examples

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, devops, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

We are trying to get a good pipeline for CI/CD up and running on Azure Devops. We have reusable templates that can handle things like building the UI pieces, microservices, databases, etc., (and can package and/or deploy them).

What I am wondering about is how to tie it all together and whether it should all be under one generic CI/CD pipeline, and if so, what triggers it (every commit, just PR acceptance to main, something else)?

We intend to do development in small, continuous increments and are open to situations where a given user story is contained to one aspect of the system, but we are also open to more feature-specific, but still small, user stories such that the commit(s) span UI, service and dbs. Whatever makes the most sense from a continuous delivery approach.

What I am looking for are maybe some case studies/opinions from people who have succeeded in doing this. What has worked, what didn't, etc.? Could you show examples of what your pipeline looks like? Where manual gates are? Does one large pipeline build/deploy all layers or do you have separate pipelines and separate triggers for things (database versus service, or even separate for each microservice)?

We are specifically targeting Azure Devops, but I don't think that should change the approach taken. TIA!

Comment: are't there plenty examples in github?(just learn for your favourite projects cicd workflows).

Comment: I haven't come across any TBH. I found an older article that referenced some but the links were dead. https://spring.io/blog/2016/05/31/zero-downtime-deployment-with-a-database When I googled for those I didn't come up with any - got a LOT of links from companies trying to sell me stuff though... Maybe it's my queries. Besides, Stack Overflow would also, hopefully, produce a small list of people with active experience who could help along the way. :)

Comment: you're asking for tutorials, but learning directly from successful and popular projects may be better.

Comment: That's fair, and I am open to reading/watching. Do you have a recommendation or a specific url for this. I find lots of things on setting up CI/CD with github but nothing actually describing a good process. Getting triggers for builds/deployments isn't what I am after, it's the bigger picture of things. Best practices, etc. Google gives lots of best practices, but all are philosophical (source control everything, database is part of the pipeline, etc.). I find nothing that gets into the gritty details. Seems like a topic that could benefit from a book of case studies. :)

Comment: take myself as example. i'm in a company using gitlab pipelines and products in azure k8s. we use many ci/cd/it/st pipelines, the docker images and helm charts publish in jfrog artifactory.

Comment: See, it's things like this that I am after. "many ci/cd/it/st pipelines". Wanting to know the why/why not. If multiple pipelines are better (and why) or if a single "monolithic" pipeline that can call various templates but, otherwise, enforces the same process for everything, would be the ticket. And, if not, why not.

Also, very interested in what types of metrics are being captured, etc. I think this is why I would love to get in touch with someone ho has experienced it to help us short-circuit a lot of the pain points.